# How to delete duplicate XML data with specific attribute

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have this SQL query

```
SELECT  r.Address.value('(//City)[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)') "City/@Title" ,   
        (SELECT  r1.FirstName , r1.SecondName 
         FROM Reader r1
         where r.Address.value('(//City)[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)') = r1.Address.value('(//City)[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
         FOR XML RAW('Reader'),TYPE) AS "City/Readers"
FROM Reader r
FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('Cities');
```

This query produces such data:

```
<Cities>
  <City Title="New York">
    <Readers>
      <Reader FirstName="JON" SecondName="SHOW" />
      <Reader FirstName="Poll" SecondName="Aeron" />
    </Readers>
  </City>
  <City Title="New York">
    <Readers>
      <Reader FirstName="JON" SecondName="SHOW" />
      <Reader FirstName="Poll" SecondName="Aeron" />
    </Readers>
  </City>
  <City Title="Kharkiv">
    <Readers>
      <Reader FirstName="Slavik" SecondName="Romanov" />
    </Readers>
  </City>
  <City Title="Boca Juniors">
    <Readers>
      <Reader FirstName="Julio " SecondName="Pedro" />
    </Readers>
  </City>
  <City Title="London">
    <Readers>
      <Reader FirstName="Johnny " SecondName="Smith" />
    </Readers>
  </City>
</Cities>
```

I want to delete duplicate elements, exactly the second node.
The query must generate data without the duplicates

Comment: You already provided current output of your query. What's missing now is sample input data, can you provide it? Sample in http://sqlfiddle.com/ would be perfect

Comment: This is my data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/1177

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting distinct `City` before constructing the XML would be more efficient. This is one possible way using Common Table Expression ([CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)) :

```
;WITH Cities
AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT r.Address.value('(//City)[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)') As City
    FROM Reader r
)

SELECT 
    c.City "City/@Title",
    (SELECT  r1.FirstName , r1.SecondName 
     FROM Reader r1
     where c.City = r1.Address.value('(//City)[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
     FOR XML RAW('Reader'),TYPE) AS "City/Readers"
FROM Cities c
FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('Cities');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/975db/2)**

Comment: and how this query in Oracle?

Comment: That's a whole different question which I don't know the answer. Even if I know, this thread isn't the place to properly answer that question. Try to figure it out your self, then if you get stuck don't hesitate to open a new question. Good luck!